# How can I use for_each with a integer in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following code in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_rds_instance" {
  for_each = var.rds_number_of_replicas //integer
  //something
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
> must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type
> number.

The var must be a number. I also tried to use **toset(range(var.rds_number_of_replicas))** but I found another error:

> The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps
> and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type number.

Comment: You can use `count` instead, but the information in the question is lacking detail.

Comment: With count I can not remove/add  resources without replacing some of them. I need the flexibility of for_each.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is the resource referenced elsewhere?

Comment: https://arnav.au/2023/10/15/terraform-count-vs-for_each/

Comment: This resource will be used as a RDS read replica. So, I need to be able to add or remove them without recreation.

Comment: Have you actually tired using count and have you experienced any of the issues you mention? Take a look [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count) as well.

Comment: "With count I can not remove/add resources without replacing some of them" Even with `for_each` you will get that issue if you just generate a `set` of length `var.rds_number_of_replicas`. You need a unique identifier for each RDS replica that never changes for that replica instance, to avoid the issue you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Matthew`s post I used:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_rds_instance" {
  for_each = toset([ for num in range(var.rds_number_of_replicas) : tostring(num) ])
  //something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `for_each` with a variable of type `number`, then you can do an iterative type conversion with a `for` expression within a `list` constructor within a `set` type converter:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_rds_instance" {
  for_each = toset([ for num in range(var.rds_number_of_replicas) : "${num}" ])
  //something
}
```

But also it would fit naturally with the `count` meta-parameter as described in the answer posted by MarkoE simultaneous with this answer.

Comment: I tried to apply it but I found:

var.rds_number_of_replicas is a number, known only after apply
A value of type number cannot be used as the collection in a 'for'

Comment: @EdgarPeixoto It also needed the `range` function; updated.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I feel information is lacking in the question, I think the better option here is to use the [`count`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count) meta-argument:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica_rds_instance" {
  count = var.rds_number_of_replicas //integer
  //something
}
```